# Efficiently retrieving large data objects from a PostgreSQL database

Tags: database, postgresql, jdbc, gis, postgis

I am currently trying to find a way to read large geometry objects from my PostgreSQL/PostGIS database more efficiently. I've analyzed the plan for my query and the run time if I only pull back the primary key is very acceptable, but when I retrieve the - sometimes very large - geometry objects, the return time can go into the minutes for a single query.

I am wondering if there is any more efficient way to read large objects from the database besides just a typical query (maybe some kind of streaming, where I can process the input as I'm retrieving it, to cut down on the effective processing time?).  I've looked into cursors, but I'm not sure that's really what I'm looking for since those seem to be mostly related to PL/pgsql scripts as opposed to a Java application.

I am running PostgreSQL 9.5, application is written in Java/Scala and uses JDBC.  Any help is appreciated.

EDIT - I should also add that the database is local to the machine running the application.

Answer (score 2):

You should check at what stage is Postgres spending the most time:

- executing the query
- retriving data from hardware
- sending data over the network

If you retrieve a lot of data then a lot of time can be spend when sending data over the network.
I never tried this but maybe you can use Postgresql SSLCompresion option:

> If set to 1 (default), data sent over SSL connections will be compressed (this requires OpenSSL version 0.9.8 or later). If set to 0, compression will be disabled (this requires OpenSSL 1.0.0 or later). This parameter is ignored if a connection without SSL is made, or if the version of OpenSSL used does not support it.
>   Compression uses CPU time, but can improve throughput if the network is the bottleneck. Disabling compression can improve response time and throughput if CPU performance is the limiting factor.

[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-connect.html]

Comment: This is a nice thought, and may work for some people, but my database is local to my machine, so network is not an issue.